# Yii2 urlManager rule for `&id=`

Tags: routes, yii2, yii-url-manager

I'm trying to configure the Yii2 URL Manager.

Now my config file looks like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'rules' => [
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
  ]
],
```

With and without rules i always get this route:

```
/frontend/web/user/default/profile?id=1
```

How can i set up rules for url with `?id=` so that they are like:

```
/frontend/web/user/default/profile/1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add a default rule for module, e.g. :

```
'rules' => [
    '<module>/<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    ...
],
```